# I can't get OpenSSL to sign a certificate request

Tags: openssl, windows-10

I am using OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021 ([source](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121705-firedaemon-openssl-1-1-1k-binary-distribution-for-microsoft-windows)) on Windows 10. I am following this help [page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#manual-certificate-generation) to try to get RabbitMQ to use `tls`.

'c:\OpenSSL\x64\bin' is part of my path.

My `openssl.cnf` file in the working directory:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = testca

[ testca ]
dir = .
certificate = $dir/ca_certificate.pem
database = $dir/index.txt
new_certs_dir = $dir/certs
private_key = $dir/private/ca_private_key.pem
serial = $dir/serial

default_crl_days = 7
default_days = 365
default_md = sha256

policy = testca_policy
x509_extensions = certificate_extensions

[ testca_policy ]
commonName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = optional
countryName = optional
emailAddress = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
domainComponent = optional

[ certificate_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:false

[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
default_keyfile = ./private/ca_private_key.pem
default_md = sha256
prompt = yes
distinguished_name = root_ca_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = root_ca_extensions

[ root_ca_distinguished_name ]
commonName = hostname

[ root_ca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:true
keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign

[ client_ca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:false
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2

[ server_ca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:false
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

Everything has worked up to this point. When I type ‘openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in ..\server\req.pem -out server_certificate.pem -notext -batch -extensions server_ca_extensions -verbose’ I get nothing. No ‘server_certificate.pem’ anywhere I can find. No error messages either.

Any help diagnosing this will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have now tried a different [distribution](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) (updating my path as well) with the same results. I have even tried replacing all `/` in openssl.cnf to `\\`.

Comment: What happened when you ran that command?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Console prints 'Using configuration from openssl.cnf` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K. I applogize. This was my mistake. I created index.txt with notepad. What I needed to do was: `copy nul index.txt`. After that it all worked.